# Flutter TextFormField TextCapitalization.words not working, in Android

Tags: flutter, textformfield

I want to automatically capitalize the first letter when the user enters the first name. I use

```
` TextFormField(
 textCapitalization: TextCapitalization.words
     )`
```

works fine on IOS, **but not on Android emulators or real phones.**

use textCapitalization: TextCapitalization.words,
expecting to capitalize the first letter **both IOS and Android.**
Actual situation: Only IOS works normally;

- Doctor summary (to see all details, run flutter doctor -v):
- Flutter (Channel stable, 3.7.8, on macOS 13.2.1, 22D68, darwin-arm64, locale zh-Hans-AU)
- Android toolchain: develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 33.0.2)
- Xcode: develop for iOS and macOS (Xcode 14.2)
- Chrome: develop for the web
- Android Studio (version 2022.1)
- VS Code (version 1.82.0)
- Connected device (6 available)
- Device emulator 5556 is offline.
- HTTP Host Availability
- No issues were found!

Answer (score 0):

To ensure consistent capitalization behaviour across both iOS and Android platforms, you can manually capitalize the first letter of the input text using a `TextEditingController` and the `onChanged` callback.

```
 class Home extends StatelessWidget {
      const Home({super.key});
    
      @override
      Widget build(BuildContext context) {
        TextEditingController nameController = TextEditingController();
        return Scaffold(
          body: Column(
            crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
            children: [
              TextFormField(
                controller: nameController,
                onChanged: (text) {
                  // Ensure the first letter is capitalized
                  nameController.value = nameController.value.copyWith(
                    text: _capitalizeFirstLetter(text),
                    selection: TextSelection.collapsed(
                      offset: nameController.text.length,
                    ),
                  );
                },
                decoration: const InputDecoration(
                  labelText: 'First Name',
                ),
              )
            ],
          ),
        );
      }
    
      String _capitalizeFirstLetter(String text) {
        if (text.isEmpty) {
          return text;
        }
        return text[0].toUpperCase() + text.substring(1);
      }
    }
```

Comment: Thanks. Your solution works. I think TextCapitalization.words is not working properly on Android phones and is a bug of flutter.

Answer (score 0):

or Enable these two properties of the text field should fix that:

```
textCapitalization: TextCapitalization.words,
keyboardType: TextInputType.text,
```